# Release Management xcopy Access Denied

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

I have TFS Build and Release Management, when the release does xcopy raises an error "Access denied". I delete folder manually, after i return a release and restart task and the result is done succesed

Comment: Is the folder for a service or a web application? If so, you need to stop the service or the app pool first.

Comment: I will try to stop the service.

Comment: The error was that there are files that have the read-only attribute, i add run line command to workflow with next command:

attrib -R C:\deploy\* /S